# org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: sparkr is not responding

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-zeppelin, sparkr

when i am executing simple sparkr script in Zeppelin :

code `%spark.r 2 + 2`

I am finding following error:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: sparkr is not  responding 
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.



at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR.open(ZeppelinR.java:165)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkRInterpreter.open(SparkRInterpreter.java:91)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:618)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:186)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at
```

even i have set SPARK_HOME and JAVA_HOME in zeppline.env.sh

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the R process is dead, please check the spark interpreter log